# How to resolve this "TypeError: pchstr must contain a $ as first char" from node-argon2?

Tags: node.js, passwords

I got that TypeError when I'm trying to verify the password. The hash function works fine, but the verify not!
this is the hash result:
`$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=3,p=1$8rKV3QWX0Y8GQ7ChOgVIRw$u+UEaGhG8Rvge4TvG17gnx/6jhdmePh9s7V3aK/asXA`
this verify function I use:

```
function comparePassword(candidatePassword){
    try {
        return argon2.verify candidatePassword, user.password
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

And this is the hash function:

```
try {
    hash = await argon2.hash(password)
    user.password = hash
    next()
}
catch (err) {
    next(err)
}
```

### My enviremt

Archlinux GNOME version 3.34.3
NodeJS v11.15.0
Argon2 v0.25.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message gives you a hint: *pchstr must contain a $ as first char*. Every encoded representation of a hash generated by argon2 has its first part to be the variant of Argon2 being used, which in your case is argon2i. Your `candidatePassword` likely does not have '$' as its first character, and even if it did, you will have other problems. This is a start though!

If you pay attention to the code example in [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argon2) more closely, you will notice it is

`argon2.verify("<big long hash>", "password")` and not

`argon2.verify("password","<big long hash>")` as you have done.

TLDR: Swap your arguments to match the parameters for `argon2.verify`.

Comment: Odd because i had the exact problem and your answer solved this. I don't usually have this type of issue. Something in the autocomplete making us think the first parameter is password or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @momo solution, My problem was that I was using plain password fetched from db, but it must be argon password saved with `argon.hash` method.